# Stack Overflow formatting for Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, prettify

I've become so accustomed to stack overflow style formatting that I find it a hassle to format things manually in HTML anymore - specifically for blog posts.

Is there anything enabling stack overflow style formatting for word press?

Something akin to the markdown plugin for wordpress - http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/markdown-for-wordpress-and-bbpress/

Also, I'm not sure if this is meta enough for it to belong on meta overflow

Comment: Nope, this pertains to WordPress more than Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to use the [Code Block Enabler](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/code-block-enabler/) plugin which encapsulates [Google Prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/) which is the same code formatter that Stack Overflow uses.  Once you have turned that on simply alter the CSS for prettify to match the Stack Overflow colors.  (Shameless plug: I did the same thing myself [on my blog](http://togaroga.com) because I liked the formatting here as well).